# Custom hardware GD32F103 (STM clone) broken after uploading Arduino sketch for ESP32

Tags: arduino, stm32, esp32

I'm developing a project with custom hardware and an STM32F103, however, due to lack of stock until next year, I have proceeded with the clone GD32F103CBT6.

One of the problems I'm encountering is the serial port/UART. Another one is that today I uploaded to the GD32 an ESP32 sketch by accident, and now the microcontroller is not found by the ST-Link.

I have tried to use the ST-Link Utility to try to erase its flash, but for some reason it won't work. Is it possible that it got physically damaged? If so, how can I avoid that from happening? I'm trying to use `#ifdef` conditions but it won't do what I want (prevent the sketch from being uploaded).

Comment: You probably overwrote part of the boot loader

Comment: Assuming you connected the board via USB-to-serial connection, @mmmm is probably right. In that case, you can set the jumper for BOOT0 to upload a bootloader again.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution in this video!
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jEz0C2bT2M0&ab_channel=BuildYourCNC
Basically use ST-Link Utility, connect the reset pin to GND (ideally through a pd resistor) select the option erase flash and disconnect the reset pin from gnd right away. It will factory reset your flash memory and it will load code again!